# unexpected unindent in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an unexpected unindent for this function, I am still getting the error even when the code is properly indented. I have attempted with one except and multiple and I still get the error:

```
def showHand():

    print('This game will let you open your saved Dream Hand.')

    #getting the file name the user wants to open
    filename = input('Please enter your dream hand file name: ')

    try:
        #opening
        infile = open(filename, 'r')

        #reading the values inline
        card1 = int(infile.readline())
        card2 = int(infile.readline())
        card3 = int(infile.readline())
        card4 = int(infile.readline())
        card5 = int(infile.readline())

        #closing file
        infile.close()

        #printing values through face value
        print('Your Dream Hand is: ')
        faceValue(card1)
        faceValue(card2)
        faceValue(card3)
        faceValue(card4)
        faceValue(card5)

    except IOError:
        print('An error has occurred')

    finally:
        print('Thank you for playing')
```

Comment: What indent are you referring to? Your code? Your output? Please edit your question to be more clear. And show output from your program to illustrate the issue. Also, your title mentions an unexpected "unindent" but your description says unexpected "indent." *Note: I removed mention of searching other questions; not relevant. Also note: I had to reformat your code, as your comments were left-justified and being interpreted as paragraph headings.*

Comment: When I attempt to run the full program I am getting an unexpected unindent error message and it is referring to the first line def showHand():

Comment: @DavidMakogon Why edit the code with an `IndentError`?

Comment: @BenC Indentation matters in Python. Every that is inside a function **must** be indented

Comment: It is indented where it was saved, but it didn't transfer over. everything under the function showing all the way to the left is indented 4 spaces and everything showing just 4 spaces is indented 8

Comment: @cricket_007 - the point was, I didn't realize the OP was talking about his code, vs output. And what I edited was the comments only - they were left-aligned and rendering as bold headings. I didn't edit any lines that weren't comments.

Comment: @BenC Are you mixing tabs and spaces in your text editor? Python doesn't like that

Comment: @cricket_007 I was initially using all tabs, but I went and switched to using all spaces to make sure it was consistent and I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Indent the code under `def showHand():`

```
def showHand():

     print('This game will let you open your saved Dream Hand.')

     #getting the file name the user wants to open
     filename = input('Please enter your dream hand file name: ')

     try:
         #opening
         infile = open(filename, 'r')

         #reading the values inline
         card1 = int(infile.readline())
         card2 = int(infile.readline())
         card3 = int(infile.readline())
         card4 = int(infile.readline())
         card5 = int(infile.readline())

         #closing file
         infile.close()

         #printing values through face value
         print('Your Dream Hand is: ')
         faceValue(card1)
         faceValue(card2)
         faceValue(card3)
         faceValue(card4)
         faceValue(card5)

     except IOError:
         print('An error has occurred')

     finally:
         print('Thank you for playing')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I copied your code as-is here, and it runs, so here's a refactoring.

```
def faceValue(card):
    if card == 1:
        return 'A'
    if card > 10:
        return {11: 'J', 12: 'Q', 13: 'K'}[card]
    else: 
        return card

def showHand():

    print('This game will let you open your saved Dream Hand.')

    #getting the file name the user wants to open
    filename = input('Please enter your dream hand file name: ')

    try:
        #opening
        with open(filename) as infile:
            cards = [int(infile.readline()) for _ in range(5)]

        #printing values through face value
        print('Your Dream Hand is: ')
        for card in cards:
            print(faceValue(card))

    except IOError:
        print('An error has occurred')

    finally:
        print('Thank you for playing')

showHand()
```